# How would I go about optimizing SEO for an embeddable Vue app?

Tags: vue.js

I've been working with Vue for awhile but haven't dealt with this yet.

Basically my company has dealer inventory housed on our site that needs to be publically visible on the dealer's website. We can build an inventory api to feed info, no problem. But on the front end, these dealers don't have developers or the technical ability to consume the API, so we will build and host generic vue app that can be imported via  and initialized in a tag on their site. The vue app would then call our API and build the page. Important part is they can paste an html snippet on their end and be up and running.

All that seems fine, but where I'm fuzzy is how that's going to affect SEO for the dealer. These results need to be crawled as part of the dealer's site. Will google be able to crawl the rendered pages of this Vue app? Is an iframe a bad idea? What's a good way to test and see what google is actually crawling?

Comment: Proceed from that Google can render and browse JS but doesn't have to. Depending on your market, there are other SE that don't do this at all. Trial and error is the way to test it. Iframe is obviously a bad thing for SEO. *Important part is they can paste an html snippet on their end* - this means that SEO content will be static. If it shouldn't, you need to provide API with SEO-friendly HTML response that will be included into a page and discarded once Vue is rendered. It can be some bogus markup or Vue SSR. Consumers likely needs to cache it, so devs need to be tech savvy enough.

Comment: FWIW, it's not common to make the content of such widgets to be recognized by SE. I'm not sure it's a good idea because the content is not unique. Any way, you can make SEO content optional. You can check how Instagram embeds work. It returns placeholder markup (not useful for SEO, but could be different in your case), then it's removed on widget rendering and replaced with iframe.